# Spring Data REST with CosmosDB - Can I exclude children from a response?

Tags: spring, spring-data, azure-cosmosdb, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Data REST with CosmosDB, so I'm using annotations like `@Document` rather than `@Entity`. I have a top-level Document called `Fighter` which each have a `List<Attack>`, which have 200-300 `Attack` objects.

When I call the `/fighters` endpoint, it returns me all `Fighter` objects, as expected. But it gives me the entire object graph, i.e., all of the `Attack` objects are embedded in the `Fighter` in the response. This means the response is several MB in size.

It got me thinking there must be an annotation of some sort to allow me to return a "shallow" response - i.e., just the `Fighter` objects themselves without the child collection. However, if it exists, I'm struggling to find it.

Obviously when I query for an exact Fighter with `/fighters/{id}` I'd want the entire object back, including all the `Attack` objects.

Is there a way to do that?

This is my Fighter document:

```java
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.core.mapping.Document;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.core.mapping.PartitionKey;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "fighters")
public class Fighter {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @PartitionKey
    private String game;
    private String name;

    private List<AttackDoc> attacks;
}
```

The `attacks` field is the one I don't want to be fully populated when I make a `/fighters` GET request.
`Attack` is just a POJO with a whole load of fields.

My Repository looks like this, nothing much yet:

```java
package rc.framedata.libraofsouls;

import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.repository.CosmosRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "fighter", path = "fighter")
public interface FighterRepository extends CosmosRepository<FighterDoc, String> {

    @RestResource(path = "name", rel = "name")
    List<FighterDoc> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

I know I could do something manually, like make a REST endpoint myself and strip out the `attacks` before returning, but it seems a bit wasteful.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On a side note, you should consider separating Fighter and Attack into individual documents. The way you have implemented it now, even the smallest update to the Fighter or Attack will require you to first read the entire document, make the update and then save it to the database.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to get my head round NoSQL DBs. I was initially worried about doing it the way you describe because I'd have to query the Attack collection with "select * from attack where fighterId = x", which seemed like an expensive query compared to just pulling back a Fighter with all Attacks right there. My screens will mostly show a Fighter and his Attacks in a huge table. Is it more efficient my way in this case?

Comment: If you mostly read and display the entire Fighter document including the corresponding attacks, and occasionally write to them then you should keep them in one document.
Also, consider using the Java SDK directly for fine grained control.  Here a sample app for getting started.
https://github.com/RaviTella/SpringBootWebFluxCosmosSQL/tree/master/ReadingListWebApp

Answer (score 1):

We now have the `@Query` annotation for finder methods. Spring Data Cosmos V3 Java SDK is now GA.

Example:

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CosmosRepository<Order, String> {
    @Query(value = "select * from c where c.customerId= @customerId  ORDER BY c._ts DESC")
    List<Order> getOrdersByCustomerId(String customerId);
}
```

A sample spring MVC app can be found here:
https://github.com/RaviTella/EBookStoreSpringBootMVC

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with using cosmos Repository, but if you use mongo template with criteria query, you can just get the fields you want by adding those fields as includes in the query. For example

```
Query query = new Query ();
query = query.addCriteria()..... // Your query
query.includes("game").includes("name");
```

This would give only game and name fields in the response, hence reducing response size

Comment: Thanks for the response - unless I'm mistaken, Query doesn't seem to be available in Spring Data for CosmosDB. I tried using the '@Query' and '@NamedQuery' annotations too but they don't seem to be available yet.